# How to subtract numbers in 1 column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently, I am using Pandas and created a dataframe that has two columns:

```
Price         Current Value
1350.00       0
1.75          0
3.50          0
5.50          0
```

How Do I subtract the first value, and then subtract the sum of the previous two values, continuously (Similar to excel) like this:

```
Price         Current
1350.00       1350.00
1.75          1348.25
3.50          1344.75
5.50          1339.25
```

How can this be done for more than just four rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will achieve what you need , `cumsum`

```
1350*2-df.Price.cumsum()
Out[304]: 
0    1350.00
1    1348.25
2    1344.75
3    1339.25
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

After assign it back

```
df.Current=1350*2-df.Price.cumsum()
df
Out[308]: 
     Price  Current
0  1350.00  1350.00
1     1.75  1348.25
2     3.50  1344.75
3     5.50  1339.25
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer once I can. Out of curiosity, why do you multiply 1350*2?

Comment: @sshah98 cause you want to cum subtract , I am using cumsum here, then we need using initial value multiple 2 to subtract it :-)